# Toggle floating filter in Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I am trying to have the display of the floating filter be determined by a switch or button click. Seems simple enough. I should just be able to toggle between true and false, supply that value to the floating filter in the grid options, and refresh the header right? Unfortunately, the grid always seems to be one step behind. When I click the first time, nothing happens. When I toggle the switch back to false is when the floating filter comes up. The floating filter will then continue to appear (when the switch is false) and disappear (when the switch is true). To make things even weirder, if I toggle the floating filter switch a few times and then try toggling the rowGroupPanelShow (which I am also trying to have toggleable), it will trigger the floating filter to switch to whatever value it was not previously. But only once.

I have tried a few variations on this. I've tried switches and buttons. I've tried watchers and writing my own functions to toggle true and false. I've tried calling `this.gridApi.refreshHeader()` within the same function as the toggle and calling it from it's own function. I've tried calling `this.columnApi.resetColumnState()` (works for resetting grouping). Everything console logs correctly but the grid always seems to be one step behind.

Here's a link to a plunker that I took from ag-grid's website and modified to demonstrate the behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/Me51NOVOCbmvFxx95WpP?p=preview

Here is the switch and the grid:

```
<v-layout row wrap justify-center>
  <v-flex xs6 sm2 md2>
    <v-switch
      class="switch"
      color="blue"
      id="filterSwitch"
      label="Floating Filter"
      v-model="filterSwitch"
    ></v-switch>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs6 sm2 md2>
    <v-switch
      class="switch"
      color="blue"
      id="groupSwitch"
      label="Row Grouping Panel"
      v-model="groupSwitch"
    ></v-switch>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
<div class="buys">
  <ag-grid-vue
  id="personTableAgGridTest"
  style="width: 100%; height: 65vh;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  :columnDefs="columnDefs"
  :rowData="rowData"
  :cacheBlockSize="cacheBlockSize"
  :rowModelType="rowModelType"
  :enableColResize="true"
  :enableFilter="true"
  :enableSorting="true"
  :rowSelection="rowSelection"
  :animateRows="true"
  :floatingFilter="floatingFilter"
  :maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests="maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests"
  :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
  :columnTypes="columnTypes"
  :sideBar="sideBar"
  :rowGroupPanelShow="rowGroupPanelShow"
  :gridReady="onGridReady"
  >

  </ag-grid-vue>
```

Here is the relevant bound data

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: null,
      rowData: null,
      cacheBlockSize: 250,
      rowSelection: 'multiple',
      maxBlocksInCache: 5,
      gridApi: null,
      columnApi: null,
      rowGroupPanelShow: 'always',
      floatingFilter: false,
      filterSwitch: false,
      groupSwitch: false,
      rowModelType: 'serverSide',
      maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 1,
```

Here are the functions/watchers

```
    resetColumns () {
      this.columnApi.resetColumnState()
    },
    refreshHeader2 () {
      console.log('in refresh header', this.floatingFilter)
      this.gridApi.refreshHeader()
      // this.resetColumns()
    }
 },
  watch: {
    filterSwitch (val) {
      console.log('val', val, this.floatingFilter)
      this.floatingFilter = !this.floatingFilter
      this.refreshHeader2()
    },
```

Expected: Whether or not the floating filter is shown should be toggled by a switch. Passing the value of the switch to the grid and then refreshing the header should accomplish this.

Actual: Grid seems to be one step behind (shows floating filter when switch is false).

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer with a demo showing the problem. You can try starting from this: https://plnkr.co/edit/RQcNJT2sKcv65JzNMmeU?p=preview. Or any of the other examples from the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @thirtydot. I just added a link to a plunker that I grabbed from ag-grid's website and modified to show what is happening. https://plnkr.co/edit/Me51NOVOCbmvFxx95WpP?p=preview

Comment: I don't know Vue.js very well, but I have an inkling of what could be happening. This seems to help: https://plnkr.co/edit/9NAfPeEu8GgJw7okqz77?p=preview. I don't have a clue what's going on with "Reset Columns" and didn't investigate.

Comment: Hey! I got distracted cause your solution worked and I completely forgot to come back here and say thank you!! It's working great. Strange that you would have to add a set timeout of 0ms for it to work, but it does. Thank you @thirtydot!

Comment: You're welcome. I've written an answer with a few more details so you have something [to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155050).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my comment I suggested fixing it with `setTimeout(..., 0)`:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9NAfPeEu8GgJw7okqz77?p=preview

```
watch: {
    filterSwitch () {
        // logs correctly with value of filterSwitch
        console.log('filterSwitch', this.filterSwitch)
        setTimeout(() => {
            // refresh header after value of floating filter has changed
            this.gridApi.refreshHeader()
        }, 0);
    }
},
```

Here's some general information: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779379/405015)

In React (which I know) I would use the [`setState` callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
this.setState({
    filterSwitch: !filterSwitch,
}, () => {
    this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
});
```

I don't know if there's a Vue.js equivalent, but `setTimeout(..., 0)` accomplishes a similar thing.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular: Component code behind file

```
 gridApi: any = null;
  floatingFilter = false;
  onGridReady(grid: any) {
    this.gridApi = grid.api;
  }
  toggleFloating(){
        this.floatingFilter = !this.floatingFilter;
         const columnDefs = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
         columnDefs.forEach((colDef:any, index:number)=> {
            colDef.floatingFilter = this.floatingFilter;
         });
         this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
  }
```

Html:

```
 <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [rowData]="rowData" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working in my case too.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a standard situation in React, where we need to use the useEffect hook, observing the change in the flag and then reacting to it.

In the button or switch UI, the boolean flag isFilterOn is being toggled. Then the filter is being toggled with the below code. Note that .

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
```

...

```
// initial values for defaultColDef
// if filter is true, then we can skip setting it later
// defaultColDef: { filter: false, sortable: true, floatingFilter: false },
```

This is the flag which is toggled with a button click / etc

```
const [isFilterOn, setIsFilterOn] = useState(false)
```

This is where we can hide or show the filter depending on the flag.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('isFilterOn ' + isTableView)
    if (!gridOptions) return

    let colDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs()
    colDefs.forEach((colDef) => {
      colDef.floatingFilter = isFilterOn
      colDef.filter = isFilterOn
    })
    let columnDefs = colDefs
    gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs)
    gridOptions.api.refreshHeader()
  }, [isFilterOn])
```

Ref: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9WsE0t6mQV9d14E?preview) where its implemented - shown in the last response (skip earlier responses) in [this issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4220)

[useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in more detail.